# Is there an alternative definition of finite-coproduct categories?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

In order theory, there's two possible definitions of the term *unital join-semilattice.*

- A unital join-semilattice is a poset $P$ with a least element $0$, such that for any two $x,y \in P$, there exists a least upper bound $x \vee y \in P$.
- A unital join-semilattice is a set $S$ together with a distinguished element $0 \in S$ and a distinguished function $\vee : S \times S \rightarrow S$ satisfying the axioms for an idempotent commutative monoid.

Is there anything like this in category theory? In particular, I want to replace unital join-semilattices with finite-coproduct categories. The problem then becomes the second dot point. I was thinking maybe we can replace $S$ with a groupoid equipped with a symmetric monoidal structure, together with some coprojection and codiagonal maps. The details aren't clear to me. For example, can we speak of the "underlying category" of such a thing?

Comment: To be clear the answer shouldn't be a category $\mathcal{C}$ together with functors $\mathbf{1} \to \mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ which are left adjoints of $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{1}$ and  $\Delta : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ respectively?

Comment: @Nex, it should preferably be a set or groupoid with further structure.

Comment: Why would we expect it to be a groupoid? In case of unital join-semilattices both "dot points" describe the same type of structure. Wouldn't we expect the same if we replace a poset by a category?

Comment: @Nex, I don't understand your comment at all. The second dot point doesn't mention posets. So, if we replace "poset" by "category", the first definition changes but the second definition does not. And, of course, the relationship between groupoids and categories is analogous to the relationship between sets and posets. For example, a set can be described as a thin groupoid, and a poset can be described as a thin category.

Answer (score 1):

A poset with a least element is generalised to a category with an initial element:
just pretend the arrows are inclusions to see this.

A poset with a lub for each pair of items is generalised to a category with sums:
just pretend the arrows are inclusions within the sum universal property and from
that you can obtain the lub properties.

For your second point, the idea is essentially the same:
you want a category with an inital object and a functor that assisgns pairs of objects
to their sum within the category.

*[Categories can be thought of as coherently constructive lattices!](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOsevOqt_OAhUCGx4KHe--BXwQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.nott.ac.uk%2F~psarb2%2FMPC%2FBeautifulTheorem.ps.gz&usg=AFQjCNHMwC7lFKDCFbiZ8ZiMzGjNrILYvg&sig2=Vb4WzhbRMBZIm8jZSvK46Q)*

Comment: Do you know any articles similar to the linked article that use more standardized notation? I find it really hard to follow.

Comment: While their notation is not in the majority, it is standard among a relatively large group...and what they have to say is definitely worth learning a few notation that they actually define..

Comment: `The best mathematics produced in any given century neither completely ignores the dominant paradigm(s) of that century, nor allows itself to be trapped by them. It works at the edges of established mathematics, moving freely between civilization and unfettered jungle. We should create more mathematics that is moderately subversive, that makes use of existing ideas when they're appropriate but ventures deep into the jungle when they're not.` --goblin .

Answer (score -1):

Here are some possible definitions of a finite coproduct category, essentially generalizing the definitions you had.

- A finite coproduct category is a category with an initial object such that any pair of objects has a coproduct.
- A finite coproduct category is a category $\mathcal{C}$ equipped with functors $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}$ and $1\to \mathcal{C}$ that are left adjoints to the diagonal functor $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$ and the unique functor $\mathcal{C}\to 1$ respectively. This was already mentioned in the comments.
- A finite coproduct category is a symmetric monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,I,\alpha,\rho,\lambda,\sigma)$ equipped with codiagonals, i.e. a monoidal natural transformation with components $A\otimes A\to A$ and a monoidal natural transformation with components $I\to A$ such that certain diagrams commute. These diagrams are essentially the unit-counit equations from the previous definition, so in a sense we're only doing a change of language here. On the other hand, those same equations could be interpreted as equipping each object with the structure of a monoid, which leads to our final definition.
- A finite coproduct category is a symmetric monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes,I,\alpha,\rho,\lambda,\sigma)$ such that the forgetful functor $cMon(\mathcal{C})\to\mathcal{C}$ is an isomorphism, where  $cMon(\mathcal{C})$ is the category of commutative monoids in $\mathcal{C}$.

Assuming enough choice these amount to the same thing.